# Como reduzir o espaçamento das TABS com os cantos da view usando CSS - Asp.Net MVC

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

Quando insiro uma tab na minha view, há um espaçamento muito exagerado com as bordas da page dentro da modal. Estou usando um framework chamado Remark, mas acredito que isso possa se resolver com CSS. Alguém sabe como fazer isso?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```html
<div class="panel">
    <div class="panel-body container-fluid">
        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <vc:summary />
            <div class="nav-tabs-horizontal" data-plugin="tabs">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-tabs-line tabs-line-top" role="tablist">
                    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                        <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#tabDadosGerais"
                           aria-controls="exampleTabsOne" role="tab">Dados Gerais</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#exampleTabsTwo"
                           aria-controls="exampleTabsTwo" role="tab">Endereços</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#exampleTabsThree"
                           aria-controls="exampleTabsThree" role="tab">Documentos</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#exampleTabsThree"
                           aria-controls="exampleTabsThree" role="tab">Contatos</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#exampleTabsFour"
                           aria-controls="exampleTabsFour" role="tab">Javascript</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown nav-item" role="presentation">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle nav-link" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" aria-expanded="false">Menu </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <a class="active dropdown-item" data-toggle="tab" href="#exampleTabsOne" aria-controls="exampleTabsOne"
                               role="tab">Home</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" data-toggle="tab" href="#exampleTabsTwo" aria-controls="exampleTabsTwo"
                               role="tab">Components</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" data-toggle="tab" href="#exampleTabsThree" aria-controls="exampleTabsThree"
                               role="tab">Css</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" data-toggle="tab" href="#exampleTabsFour" aria-controls="exampleTabsFour"
                               role="tab">Javascript</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <div class="tab-content pt-10">
                    <div class="tab-pane active" id="tabDadosGerais" role="tabpanel">


                            @await Html.PartialAsync("_Pessoa")

                            @if (Model.PessoaNatureza == PessoaNatureza.Fisica)
                            {
                                <div id="divPessoaFisica">
                                    <!--style="display:none"-->
                                    @await Html.PartialAsync("_PessoaFisica")
                                </div>
                            }
                            else if (Model.PessoaNatureza == PessoaNatureza.Juridica)
                            {
                                <div id="divPessoaJuridica">
                                    @await Html.PartialAsync("_PessoaJuridica")
                                </div>
                            }


                        @*<div class="dropdown">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" id="exampleColorDropdown2"
                                        data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                                    Primary
                                </button>
                                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-primary" aria-labelledby="exampleColorDropdown2"
                                     role="menu">
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0)" role="menuitem">Action</a>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0)" role="menuitem">Another action</a>
                                    <a class="active dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0)" role="menuitem">Something else here</a>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0)" role="menuitem">Separated link</a>
                                </div>

                            </div>*@

                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane" id="exampleTabsTwo" role="tabpanel">
                        Negant parvos fructu nostram mutans supplicii ac dissentias, maius tibi licebit
                        ruinae philosophia. Salutatus repellere titillaret expetendum
                        ipsi. Cupiditates intellegam exercitumque privatio concederetur,
                        sempiternum, verbis malint dissensio nullas noctesque earumque.
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane" id="exampleTabsThree" role="tabpanel">
                        Benivole horrent tantalo fuisset adamare fugiendam tractatos indicaverunt animis
                        chaere, brevi minuendas, ubi angoribus iisque deorsum audita
                        haec dedocendi utilitas. Panaetium erimus platonem varias
                        imperitos animum, iudiciorumque operis multa disputando.
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane" id="exampleTabsFour" role="tabpanel">
                        Metus subtilius texit consilio fugiendam, opinionum levius amici inertissimae pecuniae
                        tribus ordiamur, alienus artes solitudo, minime praesidia
                        proficiscuntur reiciat detracta involuta veterum. Rutilius
                        quis honestatis hominum, quisquis percussit sibi explicari.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Provavelmente tem um padding ou margin aplicados. Testa colocando um padding: 0 na tua classe .panel

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda @Bia Silva. Encontrei agora 4 classes pt-10 pl-15 pr-15 que setam o padding diretamente no html... Funcionou!!!!! Obrigado :)

Comment: Bacana, fico feliz por ter te ajudado! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se você for no seu css, provavelmente na classe `.panel` terá um `padding`, é só setar ele para 0, `padding: 0;`.

Ou na classe `.panel-body` ou `.container-fluid` tem um `margin`, também é só setar para 0, `margin: 0;`

Caso você tenha um *style.css* é só colocar:

```
.panel{
     padding: 0;
}
```

ou

```
.panel-body{
     margin: 0;
}
```

ou

```
.container-fluid{
     margin: 0;
}
```

**Observação:**

Caso seja a classe `.container-fluid` recomendo criar uma nova classe e setar a partir dela, pois essa classe pode estar sendo utilizada ou vai ser utilizada em outros pontos so seu projeto, podendo assim "quebrar" algo.